# How do you position image below text

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, styled-components

So this is what im trying to achive :
[image]

As you can see, below the title there is a particle image , and each on top right and bottom left there are half square image too. For now im trying to position the particle on the midle below the title.

Here is my code sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-forked-xxn8g?file=/index.js

How / What is the best practice to do that ? thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, you have to use that image as a background of "innerwrapper":

```
<div className="container">
  <div className="wrapper">
    <div className="innerwrapper">
      <h1 className="title">What They Said</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And modify its css:

```
.innerwrapper {
    padding: 5rem;
    background-image: url("https://rembux.vercel.app/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fpretitle-image.png&w=96&q=75");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left 30% top 15%;
  }
```

If you want to keep image in `<img>` tag, the only way you can do is using `z-index` in its css attribute.

Comment: does it apply to the half circle on the corner to ? so i need to export them as one image then use it as my background ?

Comment: Yes, you can use that dotty background. Apply similar css style for "container" div.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you need something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Head from "next/head";
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Head>
      <title>Trying out next.js</title>
    </Head>
    <div className="container">
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="innerwrapper">
          <img
            src="https://rembux.vercel.app/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fpretitle-image.png&w=96&q=75"
            className="title-image"
          />
          <h1 className="title">What They Said</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <style jsx>{`
      .container {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: #fcf7f9;
      }
      .wrapper {
        max-width: 1440px;
        margin: auto;
      }
      .innerwrapper {
        min-height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        // padding: 2rem;
      }
      .title {
        font-weight: 800;
        font-size: 2rem;
        color: #00163a;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 1;
      }
      .title-image {
        max-width: 72px;
        min-height: 50px;
        max-height: 50px;
        min-width: 72px;
        inset: 0 17rem 0 0;
      }
    `}</style>
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it doesnt seem like what i wanted like in the picture

Comment: this h1 ->  <h1 className="title">What They Said</h1> must be a div and details...